# Equal height columns with display flex and its child height in percentage

Tags: css, flexbox

My problem is I want 2 columns with same height, and I used for this display: flex in container.
One of this columns has a child, and I want this child have percentage of parents, but it inherit the percentage from the body.

This is my example code:

```html
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
  .container > div {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
  }
  .parent1 {
    border: solid 1px red;
  }
  .parent2 {
    border: solid 1px blue;
  }
  .child {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%; /*the problem is here, the div inherit the height of the body*/
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent1">
    dynamic test
    <br />dynamic test
    <br />dynamic test
    <br />dynamic test
    <br />dynamic test
  </div>
  <div class="parent2">
    <div class="child">
      child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the child to have a percentage height of the parent. But what is the height of the parent?

Comment: Equal to content of parent1.

Comment: Percentage heights don't work that way in CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: So, I have to set the same height in both parent? And if the content of one parent is  larger in height than parent, how can I fix the the heights of both parents to have same height?

Comment: Flexbox gives you equal height columns by default. You don't need to use percentage heights. Look into `flex-basis`, `flex-grow` and `flex` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height doesn't work like that with flex-boxes. But you can use nested flex-boxes to make the child grow.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > div {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.parent1 {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.parent2 {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  /* Remove the following line */
  /* height: 100%;  the problem is here, the div inherit the height of the body */
}

/* Add this */

.parent2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* To have several children with % heights */
}
.child {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}
.child+.child {
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent1">
    dynamic test
    <br />dynamic test
    <br />dynamic test
    <br />dynamic test
    <br />dynamic test
    <br />dynamic test
  </div>
  <div class="parent2">
    <div class="child">
      child
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but if I want two childs in parent2 width 50% of height?

Comment: @user3802281 Turn your parent in a flexbox with flex-direction column. Use the flex-grow factor to establish the ratio between the heights. See my update answer

Comment: @user3802281 Can you accept my answer? Only if you think it is worth it, of course.

Comment: Sorry, but if I want only a child with the height equal to half of the parent?

Comment: Leave the second div empty, use `visibility: hidden;` on the second div or use a pseudo-element on the parent?